# Regression with correlated variables that cannot be omitted

Tags: regression, predictive-models, multicollinearity

A short introduction to my question:

I have been asked to make a prediction of income/expenditure of a health institution through the year and to incorporate this into a dashboard for the managers of the different locations. First, I applied different regression models. Because there were a number of highly correlated variables, I had to remove them and eventually there are 4 var in the model.

In addition to this prediction, some sort of form is requested in which the managers of the locations can "play" with the variables of the model. So that they can immediately see: if I, for example, get the number of FTEs down (they click on an arrow in the dashboard that lowers the number of FTE), my turnover increases with x EU. However, my manager wants this for more variables; so not only the 4 var in the model, but also 2 other variables that I had to remove from the model due to collinearity. And from the point of view of the manager, it is not a stupid request; there can be 2 var that are highly correlated, but are very different in terms of the approach/measure they want to take. But I can't put the correlated var in the model, because the coefficients will be off the roof (extremely high) and then I don't have coefficients to put in my dashboard model.

So my question: how do I solve this problem? I was thinking about optimization, but it is not the intention to always achieve as much "profit" as possible, but the key is that the managers who "turn the buttons" can immediately see the influence of certain measures (FTE's up/down or higher/lower bed occupancy).

I really hope someone has experience with this because I don't know how to approach this...

Comment: Another regression method?

Comment: Ridge regression?

Comment: Oke, I've thought about that. Is it easy to take the coefficients and put them in an equation (so that I can simply use this equation in Excel)?

Comment: Good question.  The "no free lunch" theory somewhere states that you cannot expect to use the same model to disentangle the *causal* role each variable plays AND to make the most accurate *predictions*.  You might look up "predictive vs. explanatory modeling".

Comment: Please spell out your acronyms, I don't understand FTE, EU. Then, maybe ridge or lasso? Your manager is right that you should not necessarily leave out variables just because they are correlated.

Comment: If you are able to provide more information about the estimates, that may help obtain answers. For example, what is the correlation matrix among predictors and outcome? How do the coefficients and se change with introduction of the other two predictors - provide the estimates from the two models (i.e., 4 predictors vs 6 predictors).

Comment: This is a common problem, with pitfalls.  You need to be sure your final coefficients are in the "right" sign, or a manager playing around will be badly misled (and think your model is crazy). Second, in your history the variables tend to be correlated (e.g. FTEs and work lead time), but if you manipulate one intentionally (e.g. increase FTEs) by itself you will not necessarily achieve the same result.